# what broke up in my eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

For some reason, whenever I create a new Java project, I can't compile anything and I get the following errors:

```
     The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
     Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library[OSGi/Minimum-1.2]' in project 'MyProject'
```

This didn't use to ever happen, and it used to be very easy to create new Java projects.

Comment: Check the installed JREs in the preferences and make sure the one you're using for the project is bound to a JDK/JRE on your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Properties by Right clicking on your project
2. Select Java Build Path
3. Under the Libraries, select JRE System Library under the Libraries.
4. Then click Edit...
5. select Alternate JRE under System library
6. If any, select JRE from the drop down and click finish
7. If none, click installed JREs...
8. Under installed JRE Types, select Standard VM, and click next.
9. Set your JRE home and JRE name and click finish.
10. Under the install JREs select your newly added JRE and click OK
11. After that, Repeat step 6.

Comment: thanks, that works, what I don't understand is why all of a sudden I have to go through that.

Comment: [This bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=266651) is one reason. They might be others that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check whether JRE is properly installed in your system and it is added in Eclipse.

2. You can try re-installing JDK in your system and
3. Add JRE to Eclipse from  `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs.`